# Garbage disposal not working: It hums, but the blade spins freely and reset button is not staying engaged

Tags: kitchen-sink, garbage-disposal, motor

I think the title says it all.  We have a Badger 5 garbage disposal that is not working.  When you turn it on it just hums.  I cleaned out the disposal by hand.  I'm able to freely spin the disk on the bottom with a wooden spoon, also it spins freely using 1/4" Allen bit a screwdriver handle underneath.  It doesn't even require leverage, spins very freely.  I've pressed the "reset" button underneath several times, but that has no affect.  I've tried momentarily pressing it, and also holding it in for several seconds. It always pops back out, so I'm not sure if its supposed to stay in when you press it, or not.  So I'm not sure if it's more like a breaker, or if it engages a "clutch" in the garbage disposal.

Any ideas on why the garbage is not working?  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like either the motor *rotor* is stuck hitting an obstruction in the housing at some point in its motion, or, more likely, the *stator* has shorted turns (e.g., from overheating). One would have to disassemble the machine to check.

- It m*ight have been* possible a particle of metal had lodged between the rotor and stator. If so, that could have been removed and the motor reassembled, replacing gaskets destroyed in taking it apart. However, you've performed the test of spinning the motor shaft from underneath, and it spins freely, so this is unlikely.
- If a shorted stator is the issue, it would likely be more economical to replace the entire disposal. An identical InSinkErator Badger 5 Garbage Disposal [can be found](https://www.amazon.com/badger-5-garbage-disposal-parts/s?k=badger%205%20garbage%20disposal%20parts) for US$115, and similar  units for less.

Answer (score 5):

If the unit is not jammed, as you say and the unit hums but does not run, it needs to be replaced.

There is nothing reparable inside these units.  You need a new one.